# Calculate difference or delta between different events in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Say I have a log file looking like this:

```
# time, count
2016-09-07 23:00:00,    1108731
2016-09-07 23:00:02,    1108733
2016-09-07 23:00:03,    1108734
```

Now, every next row contains a sum of all events that occurred in the past. I would like to use it in `kibana` and the natural way would be to have a `count` as a deltafied number.

So I expect an effect of:

```
# time, count, deltaCount
2016-09-07 23:00:00,    1108731, 0
2016-09-07 23:00:02,    1108733, 2
2016-09-07 23:00:03,    1108734, 1
```

How to achieve this in `logstash`. I know I could edit this files beforehand. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1: Write your plugin

One way to do it would be to create a plugin. The same problem is solved [here](http://www.realdatascience.com/datascience/logstash/2014/11/16/post1.html). However, the filter that is posted there is not publicly available and, what is worse, it is actually 5 lines of code.

### Solution #2: Ruby code snippet

I have found a solution in this thread on `elastic` forums: [Keeping global variables in LS?!](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/keeping-global-variables-in-ls/39908/15). The title says it all.

Cutting long story short, the solution goes as follows:

```
filter {
    ...
    ruby {
        init => "@@previous_count = -1"
        code => "
            if (@@previous_count == -1)
                delta = 0
            else 
                delta = event.get('count') - @@previous_count
            end
            event.set('requests', delta)

            # remember event for next time
            @@previous_count = event.get('count')
        "
    }
}
```

---

Was not that hard after all.